# Unity Facebook SDK does not return name field (sometimes or for some users)

Tags: c#, php, android, facebook, unity-game-engine

My game is in Beta version now, so am getting some users on both iOS and Android Platform. When "Login with Facebook" button is pressed authorization begins, if it is successful I try to get id,name,email then pass it to my PHP application on the server and store it. I am using the latest SDK which is v7.9.4 at the moment.

**Here is the problem:** I am checking users information on the database when a new one authorized (FB.LoggedIn returns true). For some users name and email fields are being empty on the database where id field is not empty and saved correctly.

**What I did:** I checked, debugged PHP side and see that GET parameters for name and email are coming as empty. So there is nothing todo with PHP side.

I need an advice on what to check, what to try or how to debug. Additionaly, it is hard to debug on the Unity side because I am not having the problem using the facebook accounts I owned and Apple/Android devices I have got.

Here is the C# code related to the problem:

```
public void FBlogin()
{
    List<string> permissions = new List<string>();
    permissions.Add ("public_profile,email");

    FB.LogInWithReadPermissions (permissions,AuthCallBack);
}

void AuthCallBack(IResult result)
{
    if(result.Error != null){
        Debug.Log (result.Error);
    }
    else{
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            //Debug.Log("FB is logged in");

            FB.API ("/me?fields=id,name,email",HttpMethod.GET, GotUserInfo);
            FB.API ("/me/picture?type=square&height=100&width=100",HttpMethod.GET, GotUserPicture);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("FB is not logged in");
        }
    }
}

void GotUserInfo(IResult result)
{
    if(result.Error == null)
    {
        mainMenu.GetComponent<MainMenu> ().UpdateFBName (true,result.ResultDictionary["name"].ToString ());
        fbID = result.ResultDictionary["id"].ToString ();

        string getVariables = "fb_id=" + fbID + "&name=" + result.ResultDictionary ["name"].ToString ()+ "&score=0&email="+result.ResultDictionary ["email"].ToString ();

        StartCoroutine(SendMyDataToServer (domainURL + "/SetUserInfo.php/?"+getVariables));
    }
}
```